# How to ignore an error in Powershell and let it continue?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to see if a process is running on multiple servers and then format it into a table.

```
get-process -ComputerName server1,server2,server3 -name explorer | Select-Object processname,machinename
```

Thats the easy part - When the process does not exist or if the server is unavailable, powershell outputs a big ugly error, messes up the the table and doesn't continue.  Example

```
Get-Process : Couldn't connect to remote machine.At line:1 char:12 + get-process <<<<  -ComputerName server1,server2,server3 -name explorer | format-table processname,machinename
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Process], InvalidOperatio   nException    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.Power   Shell.Commands.GetProcessCommand
```

How do I get around this? If the I would still like to get notified if the process isn't available or Running.

Answer (score 76):

Add `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to your command.

When it's not an error, but an unhandled Exception, you should add `-EV Err -EA SilentlyContinue`, in order to catch the exception. (`EA` is an alias for `ErrorAction`)

You can then evaluate the error in your script, by having a look at `$Err[0]`

Comment: I'm afraid that doesnt work unless I'm sticking it in the wrong place.   get-process -ComputerName server1, server2, server3 -name explorer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object processname,machinename

Comment: Add it to `get-process` or take a look at my updated answer above.

Answer (score 26):

**Short answer:**
Add `$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'` at the start of your code so you don't need to add `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to every command

**Long answer:**
[Controlling Error Reporting Behavior and Intercepting Errors](http://web.archive.org/web/20220324133408/https://devops-collective-inc.gitbook.io/the-big-book-of-powershell-error-handling/controlling-error-reporting-behavior-and-intercepting-errors)

Comment: Note the difference: 'Continue' (default setting) continues execution, but writes errors to the console (which op seems to want to get rid of, if I read him correctly). 'SilentlyContinue' suppresses all error-messages entirely.

Comment: [**Don’t do that** #17: Silent the errors with `$ErrorActionPreference = ‘SilentlyContinue’`](http://powershell-guru.com/dont-do-that-17-silent-errors-with-erroractionpreference-silentlycontinue/)

Comment: "Add $ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue' at the start of your code" ---> This really helped so thank you so much for your Help and making it available on Internet.

Comment: The gitbook link is dead. I think this is a new link to the relevant content: https://devops-collective-inc.gitbook.io/the-big-book-of-powershell-error-handling/controlling-error-reporting-behavior-and-intercepting-errors

Answer (score 0):

Try piping the server names one at a time to the command instead. Then you can error handle one machine at a time.

```
'server1', 'server2', 'server3' |
  foreach {
    try {
      Get-Process -ComputerName $_ -Name Explorer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    } catch {} #Yes. I actually don't care about any errors.
  } |
    select ProcessName, MachineName
```

This, of course, won't catch any errors depending on network issues or access permissions. So we can't tell for sure that you've actually got all machines in the list with Explorer running.

Note: `Get-Process` with parameter `-ComputerName` is no longer available in PowerShell Core. That would require the usage of `Invoke-Command` instead.